# Wordpress Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in

Tags: wordpress

```
<?php
$curauth = (isset($_GET['author_name'])) ? get_user_by('slug', $author_name) : get_userdata(intval($author));

echo $curauth[0]->nickname;
?>
```

I copy paste the code above from plugins/dokan-lite/templates/global/product-tab.php

to themes/xtocky/template-parts\author.php

Then it display error "**Trying to get property of non-object in C:\wamp\www\wordpress\wp-content\themes\xtocky\template-parts\author.php**"

How to fix the error?

Comment: What part of `Trying to get property of non-object` don't you understand?

Comment: I think it mean "$curauth[0]" is non-object. How to make it become object?